# How to add attribute to existing array using JoltTransformJson in Apache-NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

If input is something like this:

```
{
"Vendor":[{"a":"..."},{"b":"..."}]
}
```

and attribute is something like this:

```
{
"Vendor":[{"c":"..."},{"d":"..."}]
}
```

how can I generate this output:

```
{
"Vendor":[{"a":"..."},{"b":"..."},{"c":"..."},{"d":"..."}]
}
```

I think joltTransformJson is best option, but I couldn't generate desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the attribute is named `json` then this should work:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
     // extract vendor array from json attribute and put it in a temporary array
     "tempArray": ${json:jsonPath('$.Vendor')}
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
     "Vendor": "Vendor", // keep Vendor array as is
     "tempArray": { // put temp array elements inside Vendor
        "*": "Vendor"
     },
     "*": "&" // keep all of the other elements of the json 
    }
  }
]
```

I provided explanation in comments, don't forget to remove them though the json will be valid!

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the attribute to content by using AttributesToJson processor and then merging the two flow files by using MergeContent processor?

Comment: It seems what he requested was adding the data from the FlowFile's attribute and not from another FlowFile.. So `MergeContent` simply doesn't fit in here

Comment: thats why I suggested to transfer the attribute to content by using AttirbutesToJson and only then MergeContent..

Comment: It's more complex and less efficient than using Jolt